# WPF application window changes it's size

Tags: c#, wpf, vnc

I have a WPF application for which the main window should be the same size all the time.

Therefore I set in the constructor:

```
Width = 1024;
Height = 768;    
ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
Top = screenBounds.Top;
Left = screenBounds.Left;
SizeToContent = SizeToContent.Manual;
```

screenBounds come from the *Screen.PrimaryScreen* in most cases.

I also subscribed to *SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged* and redo the procedure above when the screen resolution changes.

In some rare cases this does not work and the application window is displayed in a different size (e.g. 768x556) but the screen resolution change event was not triggered.
I have to mention that there is also a VNC host running on this system. 
So my questions:
- What can cause a size change of a WPF window which is not detected by the screen resolution change event?
- How can I force to keep the window the same position and size all the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is something is manually setting the size in the code, but if you really want to prevent it from happening, I suggest you set:

```
this.MaxHeight = this.MinHeight = 768;  
this.MaxWidth =  this.MinWidth =  1024;
```

EDIT:

I found out that [SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.displaysettingschanged(v=vs.100).aspx) fires on a user changing the Display Settings. Try using [SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.displaysettingschanging(v=vs.100).aspx) which fires on any Display Setting change.

Comment: err... and my answer is different how?

Comment: I think we answered at around the same time. So I didn't copy you or anything.

Comment: Hmm...well I said that because we had this same problem before, and we were really scratching our heads for a while! Until we realized that Height and Width were being hardcoded somewhere else.

Comment: Edited my answer and hopefully helps you detect your mystery resolution change event.

Comment: 2Tyress: no worries, that was for the person who -1'd it :)

Comment: This means SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged will fire only if the user changes the screen resolution and SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanging will fire e.g. if another application or the system changes the resolution?
Where did you read about that, in MSDN I cannot find something about that...

Comment: I posted the links for both of the pages of the events. It says it right there!

Comment: I marked that as answer because the two events of the SystemEvents class were important to solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

Set Max and Min height and width values?